# sorting lexicographically by "all fields"

Tags: sort

Here is a very simple (though artificial) example to illustrate the problem.  Suppose that I have a file `/tmp/table`, with the following contents:

```
px9xc
px12xc
pqx12xc
pqx9xc
```

Here, the `x` character is meant to be a *field separator*.  Hence, the file contains a table of 4 rows and 3 columns.  (Henceforth, I'll refer to the columns as "fields".)

I want to sort this table lexicographically with respect to the fields.  By this I mean that if two rows have identical values in field 1, then the tie is broken by sorting according to field 2, and if the values in field 2 are also identical, then sort according to field 3.<sup>1</sup>  NB: *within* each field, we assume `sort`'s default ordering.

This means that, for the table in `/tmp/table`, the desired ordering is

```
px12xc
px9xc
pqx12xc
pqx9xc
```

(Note that in `sort`'s default ordering, `12` comes before `9`.)

A simple invocation of `sort` won't produce the desired ordering, because the field separators will not be interpreted as such:

```
% sort /tmp/table
pqx12xc
pqx9xc
px12xc
px9xc
```

This also fails to produce the desired ordering:

```
% sort -tx -k1,3 /tmp/table
pqx12xc
pqx9xc
px12xc
px9xc
```

The only way I've found to achieve the desired ordering using `sort` (at least the one installed on my system, namely GNU's) is this:

```
% sort -tx -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 /tmp/table
px12xc
px9xc
pqx12xc
pqx9xc
```

The problem with this solution (aside from the tedium of specifying as many `-k?,?` options as there are fields) is that it doesn't generalize to tables with a different number of fields.

Is there a convenient way (either with `sort` or otherwise) to apply the field-based lexicographic ordering to "all the fields"?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>More generally, if the table has *N* fields, to decide which of two rows comes first in the lexicographic order, one applies the following recursive rule, letting *k* range from 1 to *N*:  if the two rows are identical in their values for fields 1 through *k* - 1, then break the tie according to the value in the *k*-th field.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can cheat and replace the separator character with another (eg the NUL character) that would allow "native" sorting to work, then set it back.

eg

```
tr x '\000' < file.txt | sort | tr '\000' x
```

Now we may need to be careful of locale impact on ordering, so you may need to do

```
tr x '\000' < file.txt | LANG=C sort | tr '\000' x
```

This only works as long as the data has no NULs in it!

How this works may be easier explained with a formatted table:

We need to compare two rows:

```
ab  | def
abc | def
```

We set the separator to be NUL and we compare `ab<NUL>def` to `abc<NUL>def`.  The `<NUL>` comes before `c` and so we've correctly sorted on the first field.

Now let's say the first field matches and the second field is different

```
abc | def
abc | ghi
```

Now we compare `abc<NUL>def` to `abc<NUL>ghi`.  We've got a match through the first field and the separator and are now sorting on the second field.

Comment: Thanks +1!  I should have accepted this already, but to be honest, even though this solution works for the example I gave, and I understand what the code is doing, I don't understand sufficiently *why* it works to be able to determine if it would work in general (excluding the case with NULs, of course).

Comment: Does the edited answer help explain the why?